# How To Retrieve Row Data By using mobile Number in parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created a demo application using parse database. in this application I am  success to  retrieve the particular row data by enter the static value of phone from parse to android  code  like as:

```html
public void onClick(View arg0){
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("phone", "456767");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
 public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
  if (e == null) {

   String username = objects.get(0).getString(
     "username");
   String passcode = objects.get(0).getString(
     "passcode");
   String latitude = objects.get(0).getString(
     "latitude");
   String longitude = objects.get(0).getString(
     "longitude");

   // Locate the TextView
   txtusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
   txtpasscode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passcode);
   txtlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
   txtlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

   txtusername.setText(username);
   txtpasscode.setText(passcode);
   txtlatitude.setText(latitude);
   txtlongitude.setText(longitude);
   Log.d("phone", "Retrieved " + objects.size()+ " phone");
```

Now I am little bit confused, that how to retrieve the same data when I enter the phone number(which is store in the parse database) in the edit text field in my application UI.

Please explain any help from your side is appreciated.
  database.but

Comment: So are you trying to get the number from the EditText, and then use that number to query?

Answer (score 0):

Vivek,

Try replacing the below to your query (in place of your current wherequalto:

```
query.whereEqualTo("phone", yourEditText.getText().toString());
```

Also, your using objects.get(0)..... are you looking to do that for all the objects or just the one at position '0'?  If you need it for all of them, you need to run a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < winningNumbers.size(); i++) {
    String username = objects.get(0).getString("username");
    String passcode = objects.get(0).getString("passcode");
}
```